# References on auto-regressive distributed lags (ARDL) model

Tags: time-series, references, bounds, ardl

Please suggest books/references on ARDL model and ARDL bounds test approach to study.

Comment: Can you please spell out the abbrevs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classical textbook on cointegration in the ADL/ECM framework is [Co-integration, Error Correction, and the Econometric Analysis of Non-Stationary Data](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/co-integration-error-correction-and-the-econometric-analysis-of-non-stationary-data-9780198288107?q=cointegration&lang=en&cc=fi) by Anindya Banerjee, Juan J. Dolado, John W. Galbraith, and David Hendry. Another good text is [Time-Series-Based Econometrics: Unit Roots and Co-integrations](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/time-series-based-econometrics-9780198773535?cc=fi&lang=en&) by Michio Hatanaka.

Comment: You are welcome. The above suggestions only discuss ADL/ECM models and not the bounds test (I guess there are several lecture notes discussing this test online). If you are interested in modeling several variables I would recommend you to use a VECM as there may be more than one cointegrating relation if you have more than two variables.

Comment: okay, I will start thesis study on this topic. Thus, I asked. I'm looking at your suggestions and regarding your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The  GRETL progrmme will be more useful, if it includes the test for degeneration case 1 using ARDL Bootstrap method along with PSS and BDM bounds test on cointegration..

McNown et al. (2016) define the following degenerate cases and the degenerate cases cannot be cointegration.
1.  Degenerate case #1 occurs when the F-test on joint lagged level variables and the t-test on the lagged independent variable are significant, but the t-test on the lagged level dependent variable is insignificant.

2. Degenerate case #2 occurs when the F-test on joint lagged level variables and the t-test on the lagged dependent variable are significant, but the t-test on the lagged level independent variable is insignificant.

Pesaran et al. (2001) present critical values for case #2, but not for case #1. To rule out degenerate case #1, the integration order for the dependent variable must be I (1).

Comment: Could you expand on this answer to make it clearer? https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

Btw, there is now a user-written Gretl package for running a bootstrap version of both the PSS and BDM bounds test on cointegration. For an example see [here](https://sites.google.com/site/arturtarassow/it-s-not-really-ablog-but-rather-a-note-to-myself/replicating-eviews-blog-entry-on-ardl-based-cointegration-tests).